# Android Graphics issue for seekbar background

Tags: android

[image]

So I have this image set as the background of a seekbar. On different screens, the image gets skewed so much that it is quite horrible. I tried doing a 9 patch, but obviously there are several regions I would like to scale so 9 patch wasnt the best option. What I would like to acheive is, have the background stretched and leave the numbers proportional. The numbers tend to eith stretch too much or shrink too much.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option here is probably to create a `GradientDrawable` to set as the background of your view.  You can see [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) that `GradientDrawable` can take an array of colors in its constructor, and it will draw all those colors evenly spaced across whatever size the enclosing view end up to be.  This is the same element used to create `<shape>` drawables in XML, but if you instantiate it in Java code you can add more than just three colors to the gradient scale.

Comment: He said what he would like to achieve is, have the background stretched and leave the numbers proportional.